# Find two numbers with nearest value in a list in python

Tags: python

I want to find two numbers in a list with the least difference.

Like this

```
min_diff([3, 10, 6, 9, 5, 1, 2, 7, 6, 8])
```

should return `(6, 6)`.

So first step using *sorted* get the list in a right order.

i haven't look at the answers, now i tried

then found my code months ago, which is right

```
def min_diff (xs):
    xs=sorted(xs)
    distance = max(xs) - min(xs)
    for i in range(len(xs)-1):
        if xs[i+1] - xs[i] < distance:
            distance = xs[i+1] - xs[i] 
    for i in range(len(xs)-1):
        if xs[i+1] - xs[i] == distance:
            print (xs[i],xs[i+1])
```

Comment: You could sort them then iterate through and find the smallest difference between an adjacent pair. Or are you actually asking how to sort a list?

Comment: If you have `l = [3, 10, 6, 9, 5, 1, 2, 7, 6, 8]` use `sorted(l)` to get it sorted then run over elements and get differences.

Comment: You already know to use a sorting method.  Where are you stuck?  You've provided no coding attempt.  Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is not acceptable, especially when you've failed to search for help before posting.

Comment: i need a hint..that's why i'm stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on your problem:

```
def min_diff(nums):
    nums = sorted(nums)
    distance = nums[-1] - nums[0] + 1
    shortest = None
    for i in range(0, len(nums) - 1):
        newDistance = nums[i+1] - nums[i]
        if newDistance < distance:
            distance = newDistance
            shortest = (nums[i], nums[i+1])
    return shortest

print(min_diff([3, 10, 6, 9, 5, 1, 2, 7, 6, 8]))
```

Result:

```
(6, 6)
```

Comment: I suggest `distance = nums[-1]-nums[0]+1`, guaranteed to be longer than the sought gap. It's perfectly possible that the numbers in the list could all be 1e99 apart.

Answer (score 0):

I'll propose this function which returns the list of all the pairs corresponding to the the least difference (you can optimize it, just to inspire you)

```
def leastDiff(l):

    diff = defaultdict(list)

    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(l)):
            if l[j] >= l[i] :
                diff[l[j]-l[i]].append((l[i],l[j]))

    return diff[min(list(diff.keys()))]

print(leastDiff([3, 10, 6, 9, 5, 1, 2, 7, 6, 8]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a pretty simplistic way to go about this:

```
#Returns minimum difference between any pair 
#arr is the array and n is the length of that array
 def findMinDiff(arr, n): 
    #Initialize difference as infinite (some abitrarily large number)
      diff = 10**20 
      pair = ''
  
     # Find the min diff by comparing difference 
     # of all possible pairs in given array 
      for i in range(n-1): 
         for j in range(i+1,n): 
             if abs(arr[i]-arr[j]) < diff: 
                 pair = str(arr[i]) +  str(arr[j])

   # Return min diff 
    return pair
```

Comment: The function is supposed to return a pair of numbers.

Comment: In that case, just return (arr[i], arr[j])

Comment: So why are you now returning a string?